# Auto increment function or stored procedure using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need a way to get an auto increment number given to me that starts at 1 , goes to 9999, and rolls back to 1. I just need it to give me the next number every time I call this procedure. I don't need anything else stored. Basically, if SQL can do it, that would be great, otherwise I'm going to have to use a file or something to store the last used number, or have to create a SQL table for this purpose..

Comment: Do you intend to store this counter in a table?

Comment: I was hoping I wouldn't have to create a table, because if I do, then it becomes pretty simple right.. I was thinking if there was a better way...

Comment: There is no way to permanently store a value in sql other than ina table

Comment: The database server does not have a concept of 'global variable'. The tables are the only thing in the database that implement persistent storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is to just use an `auto_increment` value:

```
create table n (n int auto_increment primary key);

insert into n values (default);

select last_insert_id() % 1000;
```

You could periodically delete old rows in the table, if it gets too bit.

The alternative is a trigger, and this seems simpler.

Comment: So there is no way out of creating a table and putting rows into it?

Comment: @trilogy . . . This creates a table and puts rows in it.  The table is mimicking a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you alter the column itself and set it as Autoincrement

```
 Alter table modify column int 
 AUTO_INCREMENT
```